# How to find all matches of IP v4 addresses and subnets in a text file and print matches line by line with given prefix using only one command?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I would like to replace this pipeline of three commands with one. I think that it is possible to achieve a similar result with only awk or sed.

Current solution with cat, greep and awk

```
cat textfile | grep -E -o "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}(\/[0-9]{1,2}|)" | awk '{print "prefix "$0}'
```

Text file example:

```
192.168.1.1 10.100.20.0/24 some text  2a05:d014:d13:26aa:f493:ef87:bb60:d85f
10.15.12.11, text "10.10.0.0/16" =25.0.0.0/12 etc
```

Output:

```
prefix 192.168.1.1
prefix 10.100.20.0/24
prefix 10.15.12.11
prefix 10.10.0.0/16
prefix 25.0.0.0/12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any given shell command, `cat file | command` can always be replaced with `command file` if the command can take a file argument or `command < file` (or the equivalent `< file command` if you like specifying the file name to the left of the command rather than to the right of it) no matter whether the command can take a file argument or not.

Using GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='([0-9]{1,3}[.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}(/[0-9]{1,2})?' 'RT{print "prefix", RT}' file
prefix 192.168.1.1
prefix 10.100.20.0/24
prefix 10.15.12.11
prefix 10.10.0.0/16
prefix 25.0.0.0/12
```

or with any awk:

```
$ awk '{
    while ( match($0,"([0-9]{1,3}[.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}(/[0-9]{1,2})?") ) {
        print "prefix", substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
}' file
prefix 192.168.1.1
prefix 10.100.20.0/24
prefix 10.15.12.11
prefix 10.10.0.0/16
prefix 25.0.0.0/12
```

The only changes I made to your regexp were cleanup rather than functional - you don't need to escape `.` within a bracket expression nor `/` in a regexp (unless you're using `/`s as the regexp delimiters which we aren't) and I just think `(/[0-9]{1,2})?` is clearer than `(/[0-9]{1,2}|)`

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -z 's/["=]\?\([0-9][^[:space:],"]*\)[a-z ",\n]*/prefeix \1\n/g' input_file
prefeix 192.168.1.1
prefeix 10.100.20.0/24
prefeix 10.15.12.11
prefeix 10.10.0.0/16
prefeix 25.0.0.0/12
```

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU sed for `-z`.

Comment: Your example will also print addresses in v6 format, which I would like to avoid. This is my mistake, I should have indicated an example of such an address in the input data, I will correct them. Anyway, thanks for your example. I figured out how to adapt it to my scenario.